# Why is typescript throwing a "TS1005: '?' expected" here?

Tags: typescript

Dear people of StackOverflow, what is typescript complaining about here?
[image: Image of error]

When I run `tsc`, this is the error in the console:

```
src/SCResolvable.ts:2:48 - error TS1005: '?' expected.

2   resolve(scope: any): any extends SCResolvable;
                                                 ~


Found 1 error.
```

I'm completely at a loss here.

Comment: The way you wrote it TS assumes you have a conditional type (which is not the case since generally conditional types are used with generics). In this particular case how is your code different to `resolve(scope: any): SCResolvable;` ?

Comment: @apokryfos I don't want the returned type to be SCResolvable, I want it to be a type that _implements_ SCResolvable, whatever that type may be.

Comment: Without more code constituting a [mcve] of what you want to allow/reject and why it's really hard to say for sure, but there's not much of a difference between `SCResolvable` and "some type I don't know that implements `SCResolvable`".  I mean, technically the latter is an [existential type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system#Existential_types), but for many use cases they are interchangeable.  If you don't want `resolve(scope: any): SCResolvable`, please show a complete code example where you run into some kind of problem if you do that.

Comment: @jcalz `... but for many use cases they are interchangeable.` So you're saying that if I use `resolve(scope: any): SCResolvable`, and in another class that extends `SCResolvable`, `resolve` returns an object that implements SCResolvable (let's call it 'X') and I called a function only available from class X, TS wouldn't throw a hissy fit?

Comment: Anything that implements `SCResolvable` satisfies the type constraint of `SCResolvable` so `resolve(scope: any): SCResolvable` is how you would do exactly what you want unless there's something I am missing in your requirement

Comment: @apokryfos No, that's exactly what I'm looking for, thanks!